# React - Child not getting Parent state

Tags: reactjs

My Child Component:

```
class AddressList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props.state)
        this.setState({
            addresses: this.props.addresses
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>
                    <i className="text-muted">Adresses</i>
                    <span className="float-right"><i className="fa fa-plus-circle" onClick={this.toggleAddNewAddress.bind(this)}></i></span>
                </p>
                {this.state.addresses ? this.state.addresses.map((item, key) => {
                    return (
                        <span onClick={this.handleAddressClick.bind(this, item)} key={key} style={{"color": "#444D58", "marginRight": "1em"}}>
                            {item.formatted_address}
                        </span>
                    )
                }) : <i>Loading Addresses...</i>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AddressList;
```

My Parent Component:

```
class AddressList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
         axios({
            url,
            method: 'get',
            headers
        }).then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                data: response.data
            })
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <AddressList addresses={this.state.data.addresses}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AddressList;
```

The child component does not receive the parents state.data. I assume this has to to do with the component lifecycle. Does the child's componentDidMount get called before the parent's componentWillMount?

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Can you include your console output in your question?

Comment: The console output ist `undefined`

Answer (score 2):

No, parent's `componentWillMount` will be called before child's `componentDidMount`.
To be sure your data is sent to child successfully you should  make axios query in parent `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount`. When data is fetched and state is set, it will re-render the parent and send fetched data to child.

Comment: I tried that as well. The console.log still showed `undefined` for addresses

Comment: Can You change `componentWillMount` to `componentDidMount` and show `console.log(response)` in `then` ?

Comment: Do you mean the response from axios?

Comment: @5h3z4n Sure, will be nice to be sure it's not empty, and see its structure.

Comment: it is not empty. its structure is like this {data: {id:1, addresses: [ ], ...}, status: { }, ...}

Comment: @5h3z4n check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/82082/), this is how it shoud to be. Why are your setState in child, instead just use props?

Comment: And sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code the props of the child are listening to the state of the parent. The problem is that the props are expecting a value to passed into the child which doesn't exist in your state until your call is returned. Try putting a default state for the object you want to pass. Example below.

You should not place the call in the componentDidMount function because you will make many unnecessary requests if you don't add a condition and you'll have a greater delay between the response and render. The componentDidMount is called during every re-render.

```
  class AddressList extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                data: {
                    addresses: []
                },
                shouldMakeRequest: true            
            };
        }

        componentWillMount() {
             if(this.state.shouldMakeRequest){
                 axios({
                    url,
                    method: 'get',
                    headers
                }).then((response) => {
                    this.setState({
                        data: response.data
                    })
                });
                this.setState({shouldMakeRequest: false});
            }
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <AddressList addresses={this.state.data.addresses}/>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default AddressList;
```

Comment: please review my comment. This satisfies your question. If this doesn't then there is an error outside of the components your showing us.

Comment: You cannot do `this.props.state` because you didnt pass the prop to the parent and even if you did pass the state to the child as the prop named `state` it wouldnt update the parent. If what you need is the child to update the parents state, then please say so. its a bit complicated. glad to help

Answer (score -1):

Your code has a lot of bug. So I have rewrite your code well.

**Mistakes**

- You have write same name (AddressList) in your two components.
- You don't properly call API.
- In this case you don't want state maintain in two components.

**Changes**

- Changed names properly.
- Call API in Parent( Address ) component's componentDidMount method.
- Your child component has no need state. So I removed state in this. This time this is looks like stateless component. So I have changed your child component to functional component.
- And finally I have changed your axios method to browser's default fetch method for API call.

> Changed code below.

```
// Address - parent component

class Address extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            addresses: null
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <AddressList addresses={this.state.data.addresses}/>
            </div>
        );
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let config = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: headers
        }
        fetch(url, config).then(response=>{
            response.json().then(res=>{
                console.log(res);
                this.setState({
                    addresses: res.data
                })
            })
        })
    }
}

export default Address;

// AddressList - child component

let AddressList = (props)=>{
    let { addresses } = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            <p>
                <i className="text-muted">Adresses</i>
                <span className="float-right"><i className="fa fa-plus-circle" onClick={this.toggleAddNewAddress.bind(this)}></i></span>
            </p>
            {
                addresses ? addresses.map((address, key) => {
                    return (
                        <span onClick={this.handleAddressClick.bind(this, address)} key={key} style={{"color": "#444D58", "marginRight": "1em"}}>
                            {address.formatted_address}
                        </span>
                    )
                }) : <i>Loading Addresses...</i>
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default AddressList;
```

Comment: this causes the error to be `Cannot read property 'addresses' of null
    at AddressList.render `

Comment: Put console.log(this.props); and put output in comments

Comment: `Object {addresses: undefined}
addresses
:
undefined
__proto__
:
Object`

Comment: I have changed my answer. Can you check it?

Comment: I really don't see how this solves my problem. I need a reusable component which has its own state, as it will make axios post calls. also the problem i have seems to be that my parent state is not passed to the child.

Comment: My child component hasn't no state. You have state rewrite it. And change api call method  what you want. Otherwise its working fine. Customize my components to your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

componentWillMount is called right before the component's first render, so at first glance it appears to be a perfect place to put data fetching logic.

There's a "gotcha," though: An asynchronous call to fetch data will not return before the render happens. This means the component will render with empty data at least once.
There is no way to "pause" rendering to wait for data to arrive. You cannot return a promise from componentWillMount or wrangle in a setTimeout somehow. The right way to handle this is to setup the component's initial state so that it's valid for rendering.

By the time componentDidMount is called, the component has been rendered once.

In practice, componentDidMount is **the best place to put calls to fetch data**, for two reasons:

1. Using DidMount makes it clear that data won't be loaded until after the initial render. This reminds you to set up initial state properly, so you don't end up with undefined state that causes errors.
2. If you ever need to render your app on the server, componentWillMount will actually be called twice – once on the server, and again on the client – which is probably not what you want. Putting the data loading code in componentDidMount will ensure that data is only fetched from the client.

credit to Dave Ceddia [post](https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/)